# iphone: to much memory consumption and leak in case of table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am preparing custom cells like this
1) Created a custom cell with Xib
2) since I have to change content of lables in custom cell corresponding to values read from database. I cant reuse same cellIdentifier

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];

NSString *offendersImagePath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];

offendersImagePath=[offendersImagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];


CustomOffendersCell *cell = (CustomOffendersCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomOffendersCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = aCustomOffendersCell;
    aCustomOffendersCell=nil;
}
    NSMutableArray *tempArray;//=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

tempArray=[offendersNamesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

the code goes like above when I checked this thing in instruments its showing leak for this line and high memory consumption

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomOffendersCell" owner:self options:nil];
```

can you suggest me some way to get rid of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call "release" method for cell like "[aCustomOffendersCell release]".
Also you have to release all the data which you have alloc in cell like UILabel, UIImageView, etc... So, when you put it inside the cell, then release these all data.

Hope it will helpful to you. And let me know for more details.

Answer (score 1):

you should call **autorelease** on `aCustomOffendersCell` instead of just assigning `nil`.

```
aCustomOffendersCell nil;
```

Use below

```
 [aCustomOffendersCell autorelease];
```

Comment: But `cell` is pointing to the same object. Probably autorelease?

Comment: @Deepak : right but that (**cell** instance) will be retain by `tableView` , what about the **aCustomOffendersCell**  ?

Comment: yeah, but it has to stay alive till the end of the method. `release` will mostly destroy the object pointed to by `cell` there. But this is the leak.

Comment: @Deepak : Right I got your point, i think `autorelease` would be more accurate, Correct ?

Comment: @Deepak :Thanks for correcting me, Check i updated the answer.

Comment: when I used autorelase my app just crashed, actually the scenario is this table appears in a modal view and loads data from different data models as per the choice mentioned by user, please help